# Signal handler not working with double eval

Tags: perl

I have this code to timeout a long-running process (`sleep` in this case):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 SLEEP TIMEOUT\n" unless @ARGV == 2;
my ( $sleep, $timeout ) = @ARGV;

$|++;

eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "TIMEOUT\n" };
    alarm $timeout;

    eval {
        # long-running process
        print "Going to sleep ... ";
        sleep $sleep;
        print "DONE\n";
    };  

    alarm 0;    # cancel timeout
};  

die $@ if $@;
```

When I run it as `./alarm 5 2`, I expect it to `die` saying "TIMEOUT". However it exits with 0 and says nothing. It works as expected when I remove the inner `eval` block (not the block's content, just the `eval`) though. Can someone explain why is that? Thanks.

Comment: perldoc -f alarm: It is usually a mistake to intermix "alarm" and "sleep" calls, because "sleep" may be internally implemented on your system with "alarm".

Comment: It is rarely a mistake to intermix "alarm" and :"sleep" calls, because systems that internally implement "sleep" with "alarm" are uncommon and becoming more so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you trap the error in the first `eval` block and the second `eval` block does not have an exception and clears `$@`.

```
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "TIMEOUT\n" };
    alarm $timeout;

    eval {
        # long-running process
        print "Going to sleep ... ";
A:      sleep $sleep;
        print "DONE\n";
    };  
B:

    alarm 0;    # cancel timeout
C:};  

die $@ if $@;
```

`$sleep` > `$timeout`, so at `A:` your program throws a `SIGALRM`. The signal is caught by your local signal handler and calls `die "TIMEOUT\n"`. So Perl sets `$@` to `"TIMEOUT\n"` and resumes execution at `B:`. Your program then makes it to `C:` without any additional errors. Since your outer `eval` block completed normally, Perl clears `$@`, and your final `die` statement does not execute.

To do what it seems like you want to do, you could either

1. don't use `eval` on the outer block
2. put another `die $@ if $@` call at the end of the outer block

Comment: Right. I've found this in the [Camel Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_Perl): "If there is no error, `$@` is guaranteed to be set to the null string, so you can test is reliably afterward for errors."